# Displaying a 500x500 pixel image in a 640x852 pixel NSImageView without any kind or blurriness (Swift on OS X)

Tags: swift, macos

I have spent hours on Google searching for an answer to this and trying pieces of code but I have just not been able to find one. I also recognise that this is a question that has been asked lots of times, however I do not know what else to do now.

I have access to 500x500 pixel rainfall radar images from the Met Offices' DataPoint API, covering the UK. They must be displayed in a 640x852 pixel area (an NSImageView, which I currently have the scaling property set to axis independent) because this is the correct size of the map generated for the boundaries covered by the imagery. I want to display them at the enlarged size of 640x852 using the nearest neighbour algorithm and in an aliased format. This can be achieved in Photoshop by going to Image > Image Size... and setting resample to nearest neighbour (hard edges). The source images should remain at 500x500 pixels, I just want to display them in a larger view.

I have tried setting the magnificationFilter of the NSImageView.layer to all three of the different kCAFilter... options but this has made no difference. I have also tried setting the shouldRasterize property of the NSImageView.layer to true, which also had no effect. The images always end up being smoothed or anti-aliased, which I do not want.

Having recently come from C#, there could be something I have missed as I have not been programming in Swift for very long. In C# (using WPF), I was able to get what I want by setting the BitmapScalingOptions of the image element to NearestNeighbour.

To summarise, I want to display a 500x500 pixel image in a 640x852 pixel NSImageView in a pixelated form, without any kind of smoothing (irrespective of whether the display is retina or not) using Swift. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Below is the image source:
[image: this is the image source]

Below is the actual result (screenshot from a 5K iMac):
[image: this is the actual result]
This was created by simply setting the image property on an NSImageSource with the tableViewSelectionDidChange event of my NSTableView used to select the times to show the image for, using:

```
let selected = times[timesTable.selectedRow]

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "d/M/yyyy 'at' HH:mm"
let date = formatter.dateFromString(selected)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"

imageData.image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: basePathStr +
    "RainObs_" + formatter.stringFromDate(date!) + ".png")
```

Below is what I want it to look like (ignoring the background and cropped out parts). If you save the image yourself you will see it is pixellated and aliased:
[image: this is what I want it to look like]

Below is the map that the source is displayed over (the source is just in an NSImageView laid on top of another NSImageView containing the map):
[image]

Comment: You should post your image source, actual and desired result.

Comment: Don't forget to show the code used

Comment: Have you tried setting the image view as 500x500 size so that it fits the image point to point?

Comment: @PradeepK That works, however the 500x500 pixel image must be stretched over the map without smoothing, which is 640x852

Comment: Can you post the image of the map without the image overlay?

Comment: Is using web view an option? I was thinking if you can use CSS may be you will get the desired output. Refer https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/

Comment: @PradeepK done. In the app it is just in a separate NSImageView laid under the NSImageView containing the radar imagery

Comment: @PradeepK Using web is not an option unfortunately, there must be a way to do what I am looking for as I did it when I was programming in C#

Comment: I tried using Redraw contentMode on the imageView and it gives the desired result. But you will be a better judge of that. Let me know if that works and I will move this to answer. [Just realised you are doing this on Mac and I was doing this on iOS]

Answer (score 4):

Try using a custom subclass of `NSView` instead of an `NSImageView`. It will need an `image` property with a `didSet` observer that sets `needsDisplay`. In the `drawRect()` method, either:

- use the `drawInRect(_:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:)` method of the `NSImage` with a `hints` dictionary of `[NSImageHintInterpolation:NSImageInterpolation.None]`, or
- save the current value of `NSGraphicsContext.currentContext.imageInterpolation`, change it to `.None`, draw the `NSImage` with any of the `draw...(...)` methods, and then restore the context's original `imageInterpolation` value

Comment: In Swift 4, the `hints` dictionary will look like `[.interpolation: NSImageInterpolation.none.rawValue]`.